# Why composer didn't download packages?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I don't understand what's wrong with my composer or project.
If I try download some via composer I get error:

> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
>   I used to this code 
>   php composer require sonata-project/admin-bundle "2.3.*"

My code composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/", "SymfonyStandard": "app/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.5.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.5.*@dev",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.4.*@dev",
        "symfony/finder": "~2.1",
        "doctrine/data-fixtures": "dev-master",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "dev-master",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~1.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.5-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about trying the steps in this article?

http://www.dev-metal.com/composer-problems-try-full-reset/

so

**Update Composer itself**

```
composer self-update
```

**Run a diagnostic**

```
composer diagnose
```

**Update your dependencies** (note: The -v is the verbose parameter which shows additional info)

```
composer update -v
```

If still problems: reinstall the dependencies. Remove the vendor folder (manually) or via rm command (if you are in the project folder, sure) on linux before:

```
rm -rf vendor/
composer update -v
```

Comment: Please don't only provide link only answers. Always copy the relevant part that make up an answer, so that this would still be valid if the external sites goes down.

Comment: changed post, better now?

Answer (score 2):

The Composer require for installing specific package from `composer.json`. Like you have bellow package and you want to install stripe:

```
"require": {
        "chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver": "^3.0",
        "firebase/php-jwt": "^5.0",
}
```

Do:

```
composer require stripe/stripe-php
```